# How to interprete this 寝坊していつもと違う

Tags: grammar

The full sentence:
彼女と知り合えたのは、**寝坊していつもと違う電車**に乗ったおかげです。

My attempt at translation:
"Concerning that I could get to know my girlfriend, it is thanks to that I got *onto a different train when always oversleeping*."

I got problems with the parts in bold/italic.

First, I'm confused by いつもと. Is it いつも+と or a short form of いつも通り　(= http://jisho.org/search/itsumoto)
Since いつも is positioned strangely compared to what I usually encountered in my textbook so far, I would guess that it is the latter.
In this case, I would find it easier to interprete the sentence:

a)"Concerning that I could get to know my girlfriend, it is thanks to that I, oversleeping as usual, got onto a different train."

or

b) "Concerning that I could get to know my girlfriend, it is thanks to that I, oversleeping, got onto a different train than usual."

In version b, the A と B は 違う construction (if I remember correctly) would be reflected. However, いつも通り meaning "as usual", I'm still skeptical about wether or not I can make such a modification from "as" to "than".

Answer (score 2):

> 彼女と知り合えたのは、寝坊していつもと違う電車に乗ったおかげです。

- 寝坊して means 寝坊したので *because I overslept*
- いつもと違う means いつも乗る電車と違う *different from the train I always take*

彼女と知り合えたのは、寝坊していつもと違う電車に乗ったおかげです。= 彼女と知り合えたのは、いつも乗る電車と違う電車に乗ったおかげです。+ 寝坊したので

So my attempt is:

> I got acquainted with her thanks to having taken a train which was different from what I had always taken because I overslept.

Comment: 英語ちょっとだけ直しましたけど、もしまだ間違ってたらすみません…

Comment: Having took → having taken. I always take → I had always taken.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you say that "寝坊して means 寝坊したので". In my opinion this could be confusing. This is simply the continuation of a sentence with the て-form. I agree that in the end the meaning is as you say, but maybe should be explained better. Maybe I would have translated it as `I could get to know the girl thanks to the fact that I overslept AND got on a train different than the usual.`

Comment: @Tommy: 「寝坊したので彼女に会（←合）えた。」は「塞翁が馬」とでも言える解釈ですね。これは大いにあります。むしろ**私の解釈より良い**かも知れません。この場合は、ANDではなく、「 **寝坊したお陰で** 別の列車に乗り、彼女に会えた」と「別の列車に乗れたのは **おまけ** 」だと考えた方がよりきれいな解釈だと思いますが、どうですか。

Comment: ^ えと・・話が噛みあってない・・

Comment: @Chocolate: あってますよ。Tommyは①寝坊し、そして②別の列車に乗れたという一連の事象が原因で彼女に会えたと言ってます。そのとおりです。どれが欠けても彼女との出会いには結び付きません。私の回答は、②だけが原因で彼女に会えたという近因（直近の原因）で説明しました。本当はそれで終わりです。でも、別の考えで遠因である寝坊したという本来なら悪い事情に特化することで、「塞翁が馬」のように「災い転じて福をなす」という例えのように使えますと言ったまでです。この場合は、別の列車に乗ったのは単なる成り行きですので、「おまけ」と言ったまでですが、「塞翁が馬」を勉強してもらおうと持って行ったのですが言葉足らずで逆に混乱させてしまったようですね。すみません。

Comment: い、いや。。Tommy さんが言ってるのはそういうことじゃなくて・・

Comment: @Chocolate: "This is simply the continuation of a sentence with the て-form. " 京都に行っ**て**、大阪に行っ**て**、それから奈良に行っ**て**...  全て知っているつもりですが。　ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

The key to understanding it is to split 寝坊して "I overslept and..." and いつもと違う電車 "a train I don't usually take".

Here's my (slightly loose) translation:

> "I was lucky enough to get to know my girlfriend from a time I overslept and ended up on a train I don't usually take".